# Java notify and wait exception?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to code a program to learn more about Java Threading. The logic for the program is simple, when the TimeCount class count variable is equal to 5, the first thread will run.

This is traditional wait-and-notify question. I don't know where the error is in the code? Please help.

```
public class TestThread {

    public static void sleep(int time) {
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final MyTimeCount myTimeCount = new MyTimeCount();
        final ReentrantLock myLock = new ReentrantLock();
        final Condition cvar = myLock.newCondition();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myLock.lock();
                try {
                    while (myTimeCount.getCount() >= 5) {
                        cvar.await();
                    }
                    System.out.println("--- data is ready, so we can go --- ");

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    myLock.unlock();
                }               
            }
        });

        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    int count = myTimeCount.increase();
                    if (count == 5) {
                        cvar.signalAll();
                        break;
                    }

                    sleep(6000);
                }
            }
        });

        //-----------
        t1.start();       
        t3.start();
    }
}

class MyTimeCount {
    int count;

    public int increase() {
        count++;
        System.out.println("time increase count=" + count);
        return count;
    }

    public int decrease() {
        count--;
        System.out.println("time decrease count=" + count);
        return count;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to narrow down the area where it might be, rathr than pasting *all* the code

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: You need to show the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You while loop is inverted.  The condition should be `myTimeCount.getCount() < 5`